# Laragon - How do I serve a website on startup?

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, laragon

Right now I have to open laragon start all > go into commands > and write php artisan serve, only then can I access the local website.

My question is how can I start all and serve the website on start of the program.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to put your project folder into `C:\laragon\www\`

when start the laragon service it's gonna search in that folder and use the name of the folder project to create a custom url, for example

if you put your project folder named `newproject` into the `C:\laragon\www` folder, when you start the service, laragon it's gonna make an url with the name of that folder `newproject.test`

`C:\laragon\www\newproject`-> newproject.test

`C:\laragon\www\blog`-> blog.test

Comment: can you be more specific please?

Comment: when you put your project file into the `C:\aragon\www\` laragon automatically recognize you project and generates an url with the name of the folder